# Rails 3.1: Nested attributes won't save through the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I suspect this might be a very simple mistake but I've spent 3 hours looking for it so I thought I might ask for some help from the community.

I'm running through Ryan Bates' excellent screencasts on Nested Models Forms and trying to apply them to my own project.  The problem is the nested attribute doesn't seem to save using the form.  I can get it to save through the console but it only shows up as empty brackets when going through the form.

Here's the relevant code:

**The form view (using haml)**

```
= form_for(@article) do |f|
  - if @article.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error")
        prohibited this article from being saved:
        %ul
          - @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li= msg
  .field
    = f.label :title
    %br/
    = f.text_field :title
  .field
    = f.label :intro
    %br/
    = f.text_area :intro
  = f.fields_for :subsections do |builder|
    = render 'subsections_fields', :f => builder
  .field
    = f.label :published_at
    %br/
    = f.text_field :published_at
  .actions
    = submit_or_cancel(f)
```

**subsection_fields form view**

```
= f.label :header
%br/
= f.text_field :header
= f.label :order_id
= f.number_field :order_id
%br/
= f.label :body
%br/
= f.text_area :body
%br/
= f.check_box :_destroy
= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Subsection"
%br/
```

**Controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    3.times { @article.subsections.build }
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created article."
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(params[:article])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated article."
      redirect_to @survey
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Article.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Succesfully destroy article."
    redirect_to articles_url
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

**And the models**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :intro

  has_many :subsections, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subsections, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:body].blank? },
                                              :allow_destroy => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  validates :title, :presence => true
end


class Subsection < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :header, :body, :order_id

  belongs_to :article

  validates :header,  :presence => true
  validates :body,    :presence => true 
end
```

Any help figuring this out is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer to this one from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350881/rails-formtastic-nested-form-warning-cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes).

The answer was to set my `subsections_attributes` as an `attr_accessible`, so the above Article model should look like this (I also added `published_at` as an `attr_accessible`):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :intro, :subsections_attributes, :published_at

  has_many :subsections, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subsections, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:body].blank? },
                                              :allow_destroy => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  validates :title, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, but try it with `attr_accessible :article_id` as well in your `Subsection` model?

Comment: I'm fairly new to rails but isn't this dangerous? Doesn't this allow someone to do a mass assignment of the article ids?

Comment: Yes it does, that's why there is [MassAssignmentSecurity](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) to help you sanatize your attributes. But you ARE setting article_ids through mass assignment, via the form.

Comment: This is perhaps getting off on a tangent a bit but for my own understanding, doesn't using `@article.subsections.build` in the controller automatically set the foreign key `article_id`?  I went ahead and tried it anyway though and this doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "attr_accessible" to a model changes the way mass assignment works in rails.

If you remove the "attr_accessible" lines in your models then all your code will work perfectly as it is.

The class method "accepts_nested_attributes_for" adds a "subsections_attributes=(value)" method to your model.

The second you add "attr_accessible" to a model you now are forced into adding extra "attr_accessible" entries for each field that you want to assign via mass assignment. i.e.  when you use Article.new(params[:article]).

I hope that was clear.

Comment: I knew that when I set up the models.  The problem came about when I assumed that because I had `attr_accessible` methods in the child model for each field I wanted mass-assignable, that nothing had to be set in the parent model.